# remove before and after of a php string

Tags: php, url

I have this

$string="product.main.php?product%2F`1`=&_ACSS=1&_ACSSTYPE=HTML";

I want to assign "1" as a php string from that $string, removing `product.main.php?product%2F` and `=&_ACSS=1&_ACSSTYPE=HTML`

I have tried this ~ (But not working)

```
<?php
$string="product.main.php?product%2F1=&_ACSS=1&_ACSSTYPE=HTML";
echo $id=preg_match('/(pro.{8})+(type.{2})/','',$string);
?>
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: If you want to replace those exact strings, you can use 2 string replacements as well.

Comment: Instead of removing everything around the value you want, you could just capture the value with `preg_match`.

Comment: El_Vanja how please answer

Comment: @Masud What is the rule to match only the 1? What if there are more parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use [`parse_url()`](https://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str()`](https://php.net/parse_str):

```
$string="product.main.php?product%2F1=&_ACSS=1&_ACSSTYPE=HTML";

$info = [];
$out = parse_url(urldecode($string));
parse_str($out['query'], $info);
$prod = key($info); // product/1
list(, $id) = explode('/', $prod);
var_dump($id); // 1
```